# Basic authentication with jira-python

Tags: python, jira

I'm new to Python, new to the jira-python library, and new to network programming, though I do have quite a bit of experience with application and integration programming and database queries (though it's been a while).

Using Python 2.7 and requests 1.0.3

I'm trying to use this library - http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ to query Jira 5.1 using Python. I successfully connected using an unauthenticated query, though I had to make a change to a line in `client.py`, changing

I changed

```
self._session = requests.session(verify=verify, hooks={'args': self._add_content_type})
```

to

```
self._session = requests.session()
```

I didn't know what I was doing exactly but before the change I got an error and after the change I got a successful list of project names returned.

Then I tried basic authentication so I can take advantage of my Jira permissions and do reporting. That failed initially too. And I made the same change to

```
def _create_http_basic_session
```

in `client.py` , but now I just get another error. So problem not solved. Now I get a different error:

```
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
type Status report
message Unsupported Media Type

description The server refused this request because the request entity is in
a format not` `supported by the requested resource for the requested method 
(Unsupported Media Type).
```

So then I decided to do a super simple test just using the requests module, which I believe is being used by the jira-python module and this code seemed to log me in. I got a good response:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(the_url, auth=(my username , password))
print r.text
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: requests broke some compatibility after 1.0, and your jira-python is probably not compatible. I've made a pull request with some changes to support requests-1.0+ https://bitbucket.org/bspeakmon/jira-python/pull-request/11/updating-to-work-with-requests-110/diff

Comment: @Neal Caidin, Kindly check my answer as that is an up-to-date answer as per the official documentation of Jira.

Answer (score 22):

Here's how I use the [jira](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira) module with authentication in a Python script:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
import logging

# Defines a function for connecting to Jira
def connect_jira(log, jira_server, jira_user, jira_password):
    '''
    Connect to JIRA. Return None on error
    '''
    try:
        log.info("Connecting to JIRA: %s" % jira_server)
        jira_options = {'server': jira_server}
        jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
                                        # ^--- Note the tuple
        return jira
    except Exception,e:
        log.error("Failed to connect to JIRA: %s" % e)
        return None

# create logger
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# NOTE: You put your login details in the function call connect_jira(..) below!

# create a connection object, jc
jc = connect_jira(log, "https://myjira.mydom.com", "myusername", "mypassword")

# print names of all projects
projects = jc.projects()
for v in projects:
       print v
```

Comment: It's the object you use to connect to JIRA. If you are using https it may be due to not having the cert. There is a validation param to set to false in jira_options for that case

Comment: How can I login if I'm registered using social sign up?

Answer (score 9):

Below Python script connects to Jira and does basic authentication and lists all projects.

```
from jira.client import JIRA
options = {'server': 'Jira-URL'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('username', 'password'))
projects = jira.projects()
for v in projects:
   print v
```

It prints a list of all the project's available within your instance of Jira.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:**

> As of June 2019, Atlassian Cloud users who are using a REST endpoint in Jira or Confluence Cloud with basic or cookie-based authentication will need to update their app or integration processes to use an API token, OAuth, or Atlassian Connect.

> After June 5th, 2019 attempts to authenticate via basic auth with an Atlassian account password will return an invalid credentials error.

*Reference: [Deprecation of basic authentication with passwords for Jira and Confluence APIs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-with-passwords-for-jira-and-confluence-apis-972355348.html)*

**Solution to the Above-mentioned Problem:**

You can use an API token to authenticate a script or other process with an Atlassian cloud product. You generate the token from your Atlassian account, then copy and paste it to the script.

If you use two-step verification to authenticate, your script will need to use a REST API token to authenticate.

**Steps to Create an API Token from your Atlassian Account:**

1. Log in to https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens
2. Click Create API token.
3. From the dialog that appears, enter a memorable and concise Label for your token and click Create.
4. Click Copy to clipboard, then paste the token to your script.

**Reference: [API tokens](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html)**

**Python 3.8 Code Reference**

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_client = JIRA(options={'server': JIRA_URL}, basic_auth=(JIRA_USERNAME, JIRA_TOKEN))
issue = jira_client.issue('PLAT-8742')
print(issue.fields.summary)
```

Comment: Is there no way to not use plain password and not use the api-token? Other tools allow to open a page to generate a token or save the active sessions once.

Answer (score 2):

Don't change the library, instead put your credentials inside the ~/.netrc file.

If you put them there you will also be able to test your calls using curl or wget.

I am not sure anymore about compatibility with Jira 5.x, only 7.x and 6.4 are currently tested. If you setup an instance for testing I could modify the integration tests to run against it, too.

My lucky guess is that you broke it with that change.

Answer (score 1):

As of [2019](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/) Atlassian has deprecated authorizing with *passwords*.

You can easily replace the password with an *API Token* created [here](https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens).

Here's a minimalistic example:

`pip install jira`

```py
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA("YOUR-JIRA-URL", basic_auth=("YOUR-EMAIL", "YOUR-API-TOKEN"))

issue = jira.issue("YOUR-ISSUE-KEY (e.g. ABC-13)")
print(issue.fields.summary)
```

I recommend storing your API Token as an environment variable and accessing it with `os.environ[key]`.